# Chrome build with fake/mock codec

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

Does anyone know a build of chrome that has mock/fake codec, and does not actually decode the video, but the website thinks it does? I cannot find it anywhere, and it would take a lot of CPU load down from my headless chrome testing. Thank you!

Tried to find chrome that's compiled like that anywhere, nothing comes up.